# Add future dates to plot for trendline

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I've got some csv data that i've plotted using matplotlib. I've also put a trendline (linear fit) over the top of the data. I want to extend the date range so that my trendline gives a prediction of the data about 6 months into the future.

I've been banging my head on the keyboard for a whole day.

The csv data is

```
Date,Cash Bucks
29/07/2015,4010.14
22/08/2015,4471.09
26/08/2015,4685.6
```

And the code I've got which doesn't predict the future is

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

filename = "statistics.csv"
f=open(filename, "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f)
headers = reader.next()

converters = [str.strip] + [float] * (len(headers) - 1) # get numeric values into floats

column = {}
for h in headers:
    column[h] = []

for row in reader:
    for h, v, conv in zip(headers, row, converters):
      column[h].append(conv(v))

dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date() for date in column['Date']]

f.close()

date_start = dates_list[0]
date_end = dates_list[-1] + timedelta(3*365/12)
# dates_list.append(date_end)

print dates_list
x1 = dates_list
x2 = mdates.date2num(x1)
y1 = column['Cash Bucks']

z=np.polyfit(x2,y1,1)
p=np.poly1d(z)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='white')


# Plot actual data
plt.plot_date(x=x1, y=y1, fmt='o-')
plt.plot(x1,p(x2),'r--') #add trendline to plot

plt.title('Cash Bucks')
plt.ylabel('Cash Bucks')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

How do I increase the date range and trendline plot to see the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append your `end_date` to `x1` after you plot the actual data, then remake `x2` with the new appended value, before you plot the trendline.

So, the end of your script will look like:

```
# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='white')

# Plot actual data
plt.plot_date(x=x1, y=y1, fmt='o-')

# Now append the extra data
x1.append(date_end)
x2 = mdates.date2num(x1)

plt.plot(x1,p(x2),'r--') #add trendline to plot

plt.title('Cash Bucks')
plt.ylabel('Cash Bucks')
plt.xlabel('Date')

fig.autofmt_xdate() # This tidies up the x axis
plt.show()
```

I've also added `fig.autofmt_xdate()` for you, which makes the x axis labels a bit nicer

[image]